# How can environment variables be used which have a point in the variable name?

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

I wrote some code in which I need to use the value from one file and use it in another. The code works fine as long as variables do not have `.` in name. But for variable name `Project.Name` the code below fails to produce the expected result.

```
for /f "tokens=1,2* delims==" %%x in (%temp%\project.properties) do (
    if "%%x"=="Project.Name" set %%x=%%y
)
echo Project_Name=!Project.Name!
```

Windows command processor does not consider `!Project.Name!` as a variable.

Comment: UV for nice parsing code that (almost) works.

Comment: Are there any white-spaces in around the variable in your `project.properties` file, so anything like `Project.Name = some_project` or _space_ + `Project.Name = some_project`?

Answer (score 0):

Wrong, dots are accepted (as well as other special chars like `[]` which almost make you believe that batch file understands arrays).

You could have checked it like this:

```
>set project.name=xxxx
>set proj
project.name=xxxx
```

Your problem is different. You have to enable delayed expansion for this

Proof of concept:

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

for /f "tokens=1,2* delims==" %%x in (foo.txt) do (
    if "%%x"=="Project.Name" set %%x=%%y
)
echo Project.Name=!Project.Name!
```

My `foo.txt` file:

```
Project.Name=xxxx
kdfldkflkd=12
```

output:

```
Project.Name=xxxx
```

Comment: I am using SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION in the code but it is not taking it. Could there be any other reason??

Comment: can you post your input file? see my edit: I provide a script and the datafile, and the whole produced the output that you need.

Answer (score 0):

The **IF** condition below from your batch code is a **case-sensitive** string comparison.

```
if "%%x"=="Project.Name"
```

So if the file contains for example `Project.name` the string comparison is never true.

It is nearly impossible to help you without knowing contents of file `project.properties`, but I assume you need something like that:

```
@echo off
for /F "usebackq tokens=1* delims== " %%x in ("%TEMP%\project.properties") do (
    if /I "%%x"=="Project.Name" set "%%x=%%y" & goto FoundProjectName
)
echo Could not find Project.Name in file project.properties.
goto :EOF

:FoundProjectName
echo Project_Name=%Project.Name%
```

I would be really surprised if environment variable `TEMP` does not contain a folder path with at least 1 space which requires specifying the file name with path in double quotes which requires the specification of `usebackq` to process the lines from the file instead of interpreting the file name with path with space(s) as string to process. This could be of course another reason why there is no environment variable `Project.Name` defined after the loop.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `set /?`